# Javascript - Login with randomic user

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, readfile, sendkeys

I'm working on an automated test project with cucumber and protractor, and I want to login on my site with random users using Javascript. 
I can open my webpage and insert value on login form getting the element (related fields) and sending the values to the form with sendKeys() method:

```
 browser.get('url of the website');
 let username_field = element(by.css('.myUserNameField'));
 let username_password = element(by.css('.myPasswordField'));
 username_field.sendKeys('UsernameRandomicThatIhaveToInsert');
 username_password.sendKeys('PasswordForTheRelatedUser');
```

My users are written in a seperate file like this:

```
Al,40402342
John,23492893
Jack,39820812
```

How can I insert randomly the username and the "**related**" password?

Thank you in advance

Comment: 1. Load the file of users, 2. Pick a random # between 1 and number of users, 3. Enter that user's data into the form. I don't understand what the question is...

Comment: Oh ye, the logic it wasn't the problem. The problem is that I'm not so good in Javascript to do this stuff. For this reason I ask you help. Like I ask you, how can I do this things with Javascript? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read the file using [`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)
2. Split the read string at newlines using [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
3. Insert a random user/password pair using [`Math.floor` and `Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Read the file:

```
const fs = require('fs');   
const path = require('path'); 
const userFile = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('file.txt'), {encoding: 'utf8'});
```

Create an array from your input file

```
const users = userFile.split('\n');
```

Generate a random number and retrieve the user/password combination

```
const randomUser = () => {
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(users.length));
    const user = users[number].split(',');

    return {username: user[0], password: user[1]}
}
```

Call the function in your test:

```
const user = randomUser();  
username_field.sendKeys(user.username);
username_password.sendKeys(user.password);
```

Comment: Hi @Tom M, thanks you for your answer. But now I have this error:

/////// Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:Parametri.txt' ////////

The slash after C: in the path file it seems that it does not read it

Comment: @FilippoLombardo for cross platform safe paths, read [path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) in the nodejs docs.

You probably want `fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(/* your filepath here */))`

Comment: @Thank you Tom, this helped me! But now that "maybe" it recognize the file, I have this error:     ///////  TypeError: userFile.split is not a function   ///////

Comment: did you add `{encoding: 'string'}` to the readfile call? Otherwise it returns a buffer object which does not have a split method. You have to make sure userFile is a string before splitting it

Comment: mmmm, in which part of the file I have to insert it?

Comment: `fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(/* your filepath here */), {encoding: 'string'});`

Comment: Thank you Tom for your help. Unfortunately now I have this error:

////////        TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE_ENCODING]: The value "string" is invalid for option "encoding"     ////////

Comment: my bad, you have to pass an actual encoding like utf8 there. I updated the answer

Comment: Thank you Tom!  I added at the beginning of my step definition the browser.get('') to open my website on the login form. It started to write the username and my browser automatically closed with this error:  \\\\\\    TypeError: each key must be a number of string; got undefined   \\\\\\\

Comment: Thank you Tom, you are my hero! Now it works perfectly!

Comment: Hi @Tom M can you help me to solve this similar issue? Thank you!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045754/cucumber-and-protractor-with-javascript-write-in-a-separate-text-file